# Is there a fork of PHP4?

Tags: php, fork, php4

Has anybody forked PHP4 to continue support for this version?

**EDIT:** This isn't a question about migrating to PHP5.

Comment: There's no PHP4 fork. Don't think this deserves an answer by its own though :)

Comment: -Do not try to bend the fork; that's impossible. Instead, only try to realize the truth.
+What truth?
-There is no fork.

Comment: I wish I could up vote your comment Piskvor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been no known forks of PHP4 to continue its support.

PHP4's code is pretty large, and with all its extensions it would be a pretty large project to support as a legacy application.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know - no. PHP5 is pretty good with backwards compatibility and you should not run PHP4 on any publicly facing webserver if security is even a little bit important to you.

I would estimate that PHP5 is 99% backwards compatible. [Here is a blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/07/15/backwards-compatibility-in-php5/) with typical (small) issues you might run into, usually the way that functions behave in corner cases. Two other resources you might want to look at are [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.migration5.php) in the PHP manual and the [PHP5 Migration Appendix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php), particularly the [backwards incompatible changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php).

To sum it up: you will need to test in a detailed manner after migration. Most of the things will work, but some might fail in corner cases. Some things can be fixed by tweaking the php.ini, some need a few changes. In general, applications written for PHP4 are less secure than those written for PHP5, because some security features didn't exist or were not widely used. So something like [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) or [PHPIDS](http://php-ids.org/) (or both) should also be considered.

Comment: "pretty good" isn't enough. It costs a lot of time and money to port anything old and crusty. And security is one of the reasons I ask.

Comment: If you describe your app as "old and crusty," then perhaps it's time to start updating it.

Comment: If it's not easy to port then it's probably incredibly badly written in the first place.  I've never had to spend more than a couple of minutes php5'ing stuff.

Comment: Sure it's badly written. It's old PHP code. And it's not just 1 single app.